# In PHP How would you validate PKCS#7 padding?

Tags: php, encryption

I know that in Python you would do something along the lines of this to check the validation of the PKCS#7 padding:

```
pad = ord(plaintext[-1]); 
/* get the last N bytes of the plaintext */ 
all_padding = plaintext[-pad:];
for byte in all_padding:
    assert byte == pad
```

Is there a working example in PHP somewhere using ECB/CBC ciphertext?  Or does anyone know how to implement the changes to make this PHP?

Comment: PHP strings are basically byte arrays too, Python's `string[...]` can basically be translated directly to `substr($string, ...[, ...])`, the rest should be similar.

Comment: I found this awhile ago, maybe it helps: https://gist.github.com/RiANOl/1077723

Comment: There should be an implementation in the comments of the official documentation of the mcrypt_encrypt call...

Answer (score 1):

After monkeying around a bit with what I knew about python I have come to this result which seems to be working correctly for me using CBC encryption:

```
$result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$padLength = ord($result[strlen($result)-1]);
$padBytes  = substr($result, -1 * $padLength);
if (strlen($padBytes) != $padLength || count(array_count_values(str_split($padBytes))) != 1) {
     throw new Exception('invalid padding!');
 }
 return $result;
```